# Suppose $R$ is a partial order on $A$ and $S$ is a partial order on $B$. Define a relation $T$ on $(A \times B)$...

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

> Suppose $R$ is a partial order on $A$ and $S$ is a partial order on $B$. Define a relation $T$ on $(A \times B)$ where $T = \{ ((a,b), (a', b')) \in (A \times B) \times (A \times B)\mid a\mathrel{R}a'$ and $b\mathrel{S}b' \}$ .

**What I know**
$R$ is a partial order $A$ and $(a,a) \in R$.
$S$ is a partial order on $B$ and $(b,b) \in S$.
$T$ is a partial order and $((a,b),(a',b')) \in T$.
$R$ is a total order.
$S$ is a total order.

A partial order is: reflexive, asymmetric, and transitive. I can see how this is true for $R$, $S$, and $T$.

A total order has (general definition)

1. Reflexivity: $a\mathrel{R}a$ for all $a$ in $A$.
2. Antisymmetry: $a\mathrel{R}b$ and $b\mathrel{R}a$ implies  $a=b$.
3. Transitivity: $a\mathrel{R}b$ and $b\mathrel{R}c$ implies $a\mathrel{R}c$.
4. Comparability (trichotomy law): For any $a,b$ in $S$, either $a\mathrel{R}b$ or $b\mathrel{R}a$.

How is it that $T$ is not a total order?
**I applied the trichotomy law to $T$ and it seems to be true where we have, for any given $(a,b) \in T$, $(a,b)T(a',b')$ or $(a',b')T(a,b)$**. How is this not true so that it would be a total order? Surely I am not understanding something. Thank you.

Comment: Your post is quite hard to read, in part because the mathematics is so poorly formatted.  You would likely get a better reception if you [MathJax'd](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) your work.

Comment: Your question seems to be "Is it true that If $R$ and $S$ are total orders, then the defined relation $T$ is a total order?" If this is your intended question, then the way it's asked buries it and the blockquoted section is confusing as it looks like you state that $R$ and $S$ are partial orders but then later seem to unjustifiably assume that they are total orders. I recommend making a clear statement of the actual question you mean to ask, especially if it is not the one I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem does not specify that $R$ and $S$ are total orders. Anyhow, $T$ is a total order only under very special conditions.

Let's assume $A$ and $B$ are not empty, in order to avoid trivialities. Let $b_0\in B$ and $a,a'\in A$. Then trichotomy would imply that
$$
(a,b_0)\mathrel{T}(a',b_0)
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
(a',b_0)\mathrel{T}(a,b_0)
$$
Hence $a\mathrel{R}a'$ or $a'\mathrel{R}a$. Therefore, if $T$ is a total order then $R$ is a total order. Similarly for $S$.

However, even if $R$ and $S$ are total orders, $T$ isn't generally. Indeed, suppose $a\mathrel{R}a'$ and $b'\mathrel{S}b$.

Suppose $(a,b)\mathrel{T}(a',b')$; then $a\mathrel{R}a'$ (which is true) and $b\mathrel{S}b'$, which implies $b=b'$.

Suppose $(a',b')\mathrel{T}(a,b)$; then, similarly, $a=a'$.

Thus we can conclude that when $A$ and $B$ have more than one element, $T$ is not a total order.